# Swift 3 Eureka Forms change button row font color

Tags: ios, swift3, eureka-forms

I am creating an IOS app using Swift 3 and implementing Eureka Forms. As part of a form I have a Button Row that is being used as a Delete button. I'm therefore looking to change the text colour to white.

I have tried the following, however cell text colour throws an error. Any thoughts on how I implement this correctly?

```
+++ Section("Delete Item")
  <<< ButtonRow() {
  $0.title = "Delete"
  }.cellSetup() {cell, row in
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
  }.onCellSelection {  cell, row in self.deleteItem() }
```

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you are close, you must use `tintColor` instead of `textColor`, use this code

```
 <<< ButtonRow() {
      $0.title = "Delete"
      }.cellSetup() {cell, row in
          cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
          cell.tintColor = UIColor.white
      }
```

[image]

I hope this helps you

Comment: Hey thanks for the thought, sorry. I've been away from my dev machine for a couple of days, but hope to be back and try it out this evening

Comment: @MichaelMoulsdale ok, let me know about it